# How to splice a string from file?

Tags: python, string, file, file-writing

I need to read and copy a string from a file, I split it to remove the newline but then it gives me `['variable contents']`. When I try splicing it just deletes the whole string from the variable.

If it's of any use there are also integers in the file.
The code looks like this:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as file:

    a = int(file.readline())
    b = int(file.readline())
    c = int(file.readline())
    d = (file.read().split())
    e = (file.read().split())
    f = (file.read().split())
    
print('text', f) #This returns ['f contents']

#I've tried splicing

f = f[2:10] #This returns []

#I've tried item.replace

[item.replace("[", "") for item in f] #This returns ['f contents']
```

Comment: You can't do a substring on an array. Pick one of the array elements to substring.

Comment: The brackets `[ ]` are NOT part of your content `f`, they just mean that `f` is an list, as you splitted

Answer (score 0):

you can read the line once using:

```
f.read().splitline()
```

then you can split and convert the result however you want!